# Page Objects Design: Is there a Javascript equivalent to Ruby gem "site_prism"

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor, pageobjects, site-prism

I'd like to know if there is a framework in Javascript (NodeJS) for [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor) which supports a clean way to define the Page Object Elements on a Page Object as [site_prism](https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism) does. I've already checked [astrolabe](https://github.com/stuplum/astrolabe) but doesn't quite fit the purpose.

This is how Page Objects are declarative defined with [site_prism](https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism)

```
class Home < SitePrism::Page
  set_url "/index.htm"
  set_url_matcher /google.com\/?/
  element :search_field, "input[name='q']"
  element :search_button, "button[name='btnK']"
  elements :footer_links, "#footer a"
  section :menu, MenuSection, "#gbx3"
end

class MenuSection < SitePrism::Section
  element :search, "a.search"
  element :images, "a.image-search"
  element :maps, "a.map-search"
end
```

Does anyone know or has developed a solution like above but for [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor). Maybe someone is using a custom framework internally, are you willing to open source it?

Regarding [astrolabe](https://github.com/stuplum/astrolabe) it lacks collections support and I'm looking for a more declarative syntax; instead of

```
username: { get: function() { return this.findElement(this.by.input('username')); },
```

I was expecting something more declarative like:

```
username: By.input('username'),
```

Could dig further on missing [astrolabe](https://github.com/stuplum/astrolabe) features here but my question is not about [astrolabe](https://github.com/stuplum/astrolabe) per se but as whether there is a better [site_prism](https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism) equivalent for JS.

Note: migrating the question from [Software Quality Assurance & Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/11623/page-object-design-is-there-a-javascript-equivalent-to-ruby-gem-site-prism) since hasn't received enough attention there.

Comment: Hey Leo, I've not seen anything better either. I've been rolling my own: https://github.com/qualityshepherd/protractor_example but I'm also curious what others are using...

What are you using currently?

Comment: Hey @Brine took a look at your repo, can't find a framework there on top of Protractor, just a simple & convenient Page Objects implementation pattern, did you take a look at site_prism features? It's a pretty extensive list that starts [here](https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism#parameterized-urls).

Comment: And yes, I've done some effort on setting up a "A Page Object Model DSL for Protractor" but didn't complete all site_prism features and didn't open source it.. yet. Need to discuss with my colleagues what's the best approach and first make sure this effort has not being done by someone else.

Comment: Yeah, I've not added an actual framework, just solidifying a pattern. I only glanced at site_prism... I'll take a closer look soon. But I'm in the same boat... I would like something akin to Geb, which is a great framework on top of Webdriver, written in Groovy.

Answer (score 0):

I use this pattern (a little cleaner):

```
'use strict'
exports.MyClassPage = function() {

  var textName = element(by.id("name"));
  var tabUsers = element.all(by.repeater("user in users"));

  this.setTxtName = function(name) {
    return textName.sendKeys(name);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vitalets/page-object) for declaring page object selectors.
For example the `site_prism` code would look like:

```js
const po = require('@vitalets/page-object');

const menuSection = exports.menuSection = po`.menu`;
menuSection.search = po`a.search`;
menuSection.images = po`a.image-search`;
menuSection.maps = po`a.map-search`;
```